# Why does Swagger codegen tool generate different server stubs?

Tags: maven, jersey-2.0, swagger-codegen

I want to generate `jersey 2.0` server stub from a swagger api specification file. When using *Swagger online codegen tool* to generate server stub, I get a nice jersey server stub containing `impl` directory with clearly indicated places where I should put my business logic. Everything compiles and runs nicely.

However, when I try to generate `jersey 2.0` server stub with `swagger-codegen-maven-plugin`, I cannot manage to get similar thing. This is the plugin config that I use in my `pom.xml` file:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.swagger.codegen.v3</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.35</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <inputSpec>src/main/resources/api.yaml</inputSpec>
                <language>java</language>
                <configOptions>
                    <sourceFolder>src/gen/java/main</sourceFolder>
                    <dateLibrary>java11</dateLibrary>
                </configOptions>
                <library>jersey2</library>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Server stub I get this way doesn't even use Jersey annotations and is not working out of the box. Generated `README.md` contains instructions that aren't clear and asks me to use plugins that don't exist on maven repository.

I would like to get a similar server stub as the one I get from the online tool, but the documentation isn't really clear on how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, I needed to specify the `language` tag to have value `jaxrs-jersey`, like so:

```
<language>jaxrs-jersey</language>
```

Comment: Will the cli tool also generate a server stub or is it only the online tool? I have searched high and low and yours was the closest to an answer I've come across.